# Unable to set barTintColor with custom RGBa in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a simple code in my viewDidLoad that changes the color of the navbar in iOS7:

```
if([UINavigationBar instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(barTintColor)]){
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor=  [UIColor colorWithRed:33 green:50 blue:86 alpha:1];
    }
```

When the view loads, the bar is completely white. But if I change it to something like:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor=  [UIColor redColor];
```

it works perfectly fine. Is it that some colors aren't supported, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must divide your rgb color values to 255 and convert to float, like this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:33.0f/255.0f green:50.0f/255.0f blue:86.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

Usually I declare the following macro:

```
#define Color(r,g,b,a) [UIColor colorWithRed:(r/(float)255) green:(g/(float)255) blue:(b/(float)255) alpha:a]
```

and use it this way: `Color(33,50,86,1);`

Comment: Thanks! That worked pretty well, do you mind mentioning why you have to divide to 255?

Comment: because you must have color component that has a value from 0.0 to 1.0. You can read this for more information:
[link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:)